# Ubuntu installed but won't boot

Tags: boot

Ubuntu installed and prompted for a restart.  When I restarted the computer, Window 7 started normally and no sign of Ubuntu.  When F2 is pressed during a restart Windows 7 is the only OS showing.  How do I get Ubuntu to load?

Comment: You can try running Boot Repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like grub did not get installed to the disk MBR. Either:

- Use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), check "Reinstall GRUB" and click "Apply"
- Boot the install CD, open a terminal, and do `grub-install /dev/sda`

Basically this is the same as [RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)